# How to download Google search results?

Tags: web-crawler

Apologies if this is too ignorant a question or has been asked before. A cursory look did not find anything matching this exactly. The question is: how can I download all Word documents that Google has indexed? It would be a daunting task indeed to do it by hand... Thanks for all pointers.

Comment: try googling: "ext:doc", you'll a list of word documents (with extension: DOC) that are indexed by google.

Comment: you can filetype:doc as well, but I need to build a repository of all them *locally*... i.e. I must download them to a local ma any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid, there is no legal way to do it. Formerly Google supplied a SOAP API to their websearch but [it's deprecated and to be closed this summer](http://googleajaxsearchapi.blogspot.com/2009/03/google-code-labs-and-soap-search-api.html). It had a limitation of 1000 queries a day.

Currently Google provides an [Ajax Search API](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/) but it brings no solution for you as the largest result set contains 8 results.

And finally, there is the standard webform at [google.com](http://www.google.com) which is prohibited to query programmatically. (And there is also a limitation that Google only returns the first thousand results, you cannot see more.)

If you want to build a service on this, you can contact Google and make a partnership with them.