# Is there a more efficient way to get the number of search results from a google query?

Tags: c#, json, c#-4.0

Right now I am using this code:

```
string url = "http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=hey&esrch=FT1";
string source = getPageSource(url);
string[] stringSeparators = new string[] {
 "<b>",
 "</b>"
};
string[] b = source.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.None);
bool isResultNum = false;
foreach(string s in b) {
 if (isResultNum) {
  MessageBox.Show(s.Replace(",", ""));
  return;
 }
 if (s.Contains(" of about ")) {
  isResultNum = true;
 }
}
```

Unfortunately it is very slow, is there a better way to do it? Also is it legal to query google like this? From the answer in this question it didn't sound like it was [How to download Google search results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/903747/how-to-download-google-search-results)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already referenced the post mentioning the transition from SOAP API to AJAX.

The [RESTful interface](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/documentation/#fonje) should give you what you need since it limits the returned results sets but gives you **estimatedResultCount** and doesn't seem to raise any legal issues (as of now).

---

**Update**

I followed the link from Googles API page to [www.json.org](http://www.json.org/) and found a [link to this library on sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/csjson/). I did not try it out myself yet but i think it will be helpful for you.

**Update 2**

It looks like [Json.Net](http://www.codeplex.com/Json) offers better support than csjson.

**Json.NET sample**

```
...
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(googleUri);
request.Referer = "http://www.your-referer.com";
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
Stream responsestream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader responsereader = new StreamReader(responsestream);
JObject jo = JObject.Parse(responsereader.ReadToEnd());
int resultcount = (int)jo.SelectToken("responseData.cursor.estimatedResultCount");
...
```

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out how to actually use the ajax query in my application. 
If I use:
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=[MyQuery]
I can see the estimatedResultCount in the page source, but what is the best way to access this?

Comment: How can I retrieve the data from the JSON?