# how to use google search without api, just with WebClient?

Tags: c#

How to download a good WebSite search from google, because when i did like that :

```
   WebClient client = new WebClient();
   String url = @"http://www.google.fr/search?sclient=psy&hl=fr&safe=off&client=opera&rls=fr&channel=suggest&source=hp&q=dwarf&btnG=Rechercher";
   string value = client.DownloadString(url);
```

I obtain only Java Script.

So i dont want use api, is there any google clone / web page who include google which could give me a proper result?

Comment: For your case I guess it's better to use HttpWebRequest instead of WebClient

Comment: I think Google doesn't really like this and will try to block your request if you do not mimic a real browser making the request. It would be way easier to use Googles JSON API.

Answer (score 0):

You should give [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) a try - see an example in my answer to [Is there a more efficient way to get the number of search results from a google query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259671/).