# Populate html/php page with google search results of specific keywords and urls?

Tags: php, html, search, web-crawler

I need to figure out how to (if it is possible) populate html/php page with following information:

I have a url of a page and a set of keywords, I'd would like to check every week what position in google search results is that url, if search is preformed for that set of keywords that is associated with it.

Say if it is on a second page of google it will have position of 18 etc.. (count starting from first result on first page).

I then have a html/php page with a table structure which has a column with urls, another column with keywords associated to those urls. Than there should be two more columns which contain information of position in google's search and date when that position was checked (so these two columns should be populated by that script that checks the position).

I'm gona be honest, I have no idea how to achieve this nor as I know if it is possible. Please suggest ideas, code snippets, maybe some services that do this kind of stuff.

Comment: Google won't like you pulling data off their pages.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to download Google search results?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/903747/how-to-download-google-search-results)

Comment: this is definitely illegal...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To scrape Google's result pages, have a look [here](http://kbeezie.com/scraping-google-results/).

But note, that Google's former SOAP API does no longer exist. This I wonder, that it is legal to scrape Google's pages. See this [Google blog page](http://googleajaxsearchapi.blogspot.de/2009/03/google-code-labs-and-soap-search-api.html) and [Google's Terms of Use](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/terms.html).

Google writes this:

```
Automated searching is strictly prohibited, as is permanently storing any search results. Please refer to the Terms of Use for more detail.
```

Comment: Oh didn't know it could be illegal, thnx